# Falha SSL em requisição GET com HttpBuilder Groovy

Tags: java, ssl, http-request, https, groovy

Não consigo fazer uma requisição **GET** no seguinte link usando HttpBuilder do Groovy: https://sistema.planassiste.mpu.mp.br/producao/login.aspx

Já testei o método abaixo:

```
ignoreSSLIssues()
```

Mas sempre retorna a exceção:

```
error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe um tópico que trata bem seu caso. Traduzi pelo google e estou disponibilizando o link abaixo:

https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&sp=nmt4&tl=pt-BR&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception&usg=ALkJrhgf_0uYMfFV_iX1Sd2RRGubLWzzqQ

Comment: Tentei de tudo nesse tópico e não funciona, com outros Clients Https funciona corretamente.